# Thud: Can a dwarf be hurled over a troll onto another troll?

Tags: thud

Thud is a game described in Terry Pratchett's novel, Thud!

I'm currently working on a [browser-based version of the game](https://ajfaraday.github.io/Thud/dist/index.html) and it's raised an interesting question about the rules which I'm not sure I can answer from the description.

Here's how the [instructions](https://content.instructables.com/ORIG/FD5/9S6V/ID5S7XOD/FD59S6VID5S7XOD.pdf) describe the Dwarves' "hurl" move:

> Hurl: anywhere there is a straight (orthogonal or diagonal) line of adjacent dwarfs on the board, they may hurl the front dwarf in the direction continuing the line, as long as the space between the lead dwarf and the troll is less than the number of dwarfs in the line. This is different from a normal move in that the dwarf is permitted to land on a square containing a troll, in which case the troll is removed from the board and the dwarf takes his place. This may only be done if the endmost dwarf can land on a troll by moving in the direction of the line at most as many spaces as there are dwarfs in the line. Since a single dwarf is a line of one in any direction, a dwarf may always move one space to capture a troll on an immediately adjacent square.

So here's the scenario I'm a little uncertain of. There's a line of dwarves (in blue) which puts two trolls (in green) in the firing line:

[image: Thud board with a set of dwarf moves including two hurls in a line]

- The available moves for the dwarf at the end of the line are highlighted. (Safe moves are yellow, moves which can be taken next turn are orange, killing moves are red)
- There are two trolls it can move directly onto and capture using the "hurl" move.

What I'm not sure of from the instructions is this: Should it be possible to shove a dwarf over a troll onto another troll?

---

This also raises another, much more obscure question:

Should it be possible for a dwarf to be hurled over another dwarf, onto a troll?

[image: A scenario with a dwarf being hurled over another dwarf]

- Four dwarves are in a line, and two trolls in the line of fire.
- There is another dwarf between the line of dwarves and the troll.

Should this dwarf be able to be hurled over the other dwarf in order to reach the troll?

---

This one's so obscure I won't bother building a scenario for it:

Should it be possible for a dwarf to be hurled over the Thudstone™️ to land on a Troll?

---

It feels like the answer to all three of these questions should be the same, either a dwarf is hurled horizontally, or in a ballistic arc over the top of other objects.

---

Edit: This may ore may not be a clue, but only the dwarf at the end of a line can be hurled. e.g. The second dwarf in a line of 4 can't be hurled 3 spaces forward over the dwarf on the end.

This might be an argument for the horizontal hurl.

Comment: If you could attack through the Thudstone, there would be little point to it. It exists as a shield and a shelter.

Comment: @TRiG However this question is answered, the Thudstone does prevent trolls being on or past it, prevents dwarves moving right across the board, through it. So it's definitely not without purpose. The answer does seem to hinge on whether or not "hurl" follows the same rules as "move" for the dwarves. I'm not sure if the rules are clear on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't toss a dwarf through another dwarf, a troll, or the Thudstone.

Your own quote states:

> This may only be done if the endmost dwarf can land on a troll by moving in the direction of the line at most as many spaces as there are dwarfs in the line.

So a hurl is only valid to spaces to which a dwarf can move, and the rules for moving state:

> but not onto or through any other piece, whether Thudstone, dwarf, or troll

The Hurl action only explicitly overrides that it can be onto a square occupied by a troll, it does not explicitly override that it can go through another piece's space.